# Calling fragment layout in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a fragment that acts as a side bar menu but when I try to run my app it says application has stopped. I have been trying all the ways I found on the internet. This is what I made so far.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user.sample.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:onClick="menuHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="☰"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#931d21"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />


    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.user.sample.MenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container" />

</LinearLayout
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.user.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MenuFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void menuHeader(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragment = new MenuFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

**MenuFragment.java**

```
package com.example.user.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public MenuFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static MenuFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
//        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
02-10 10:11:19.236 3643-3643/com.example.user.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.sample, PID: 3643
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.sample/com.example.user.sample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2366)
   at com.example.user.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.user.sample.MainActivity@197f8eef must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener
   at com.example.user.sample.MenuFragment.onAttach(MenuFragment.java:75)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1472)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1691)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3413)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2366) 
   at com.example.user.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

The fragment will show when the ☰ is clicked. But the app crashes because of the existence of fragment inside the acitvity layout.

I already have a layout for the fragment and I didn't make any changes to it so I don't know if I need to post it here. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to add the fragment manually since it is in your activity layout. But Why don't you use the native navigation drawer?

Comment: When app crashes it is usually convenient to post the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is this

.RuntimeException: com.example.user.sample.MainActivity@197f8eef must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener

So your activity needs to implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener.

So add

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
                                                    OnListFragmentInteractionListener{

....
```

Comment: do I still need this line `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);` ?

Comment: No because when inflating the activity layout it is done automatically.

Comment: but how will the fragment show when I click the ☰ or menu icon?

Comment: You are not handling it correctly anyways. But it is preferable to use the navigation drawer. This answer only solves your crashing issue. Look at this link https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: The fragment is already added to the fragment manager, you should only hide it or show it when you click depending on its current state. If you want to handle the click manually you should so something like if(fragment.isHidden()){
     transaction.show(fragment);
    }
    else{
     transaction.hide(fragment);
    }